# I need to sort the array order of user input names Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

It should sort the array, remove the duplicate names from the array, and display the names in the right text area. Output: The list of alphabetic order names without any duplicated names.

```js
function process() {
  var output = "";
  var inputlistNames = (document.getElementById('input').value);
  var list = inputlistNames.split('\n');
  var arr = inputlistNames.split('\n');
  var list = new Array(arr);
  list.sort();
  var listN = new Array(removeDuplicateUsingFilter(list));
  outputDiv = listN;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = outputDiv;
}


function removeDuplicateUsingFilter(list) {
  var unique_array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (unique_array.indexOf(list[i]) == -1) {
      unique_array.push(list[i])
    }
  }
  return unique_array;
}
```

```html
<h1>list of names</h1>
<textarea id="input" rows="16" cols="20"></textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="process()">Remove Duplicates</button>
<textarea id="output" rows="16" cols="20"></textarea>
```

Comment: function removeDuplicateUsingFilter(list){
    var unique_array = [];

 list.forEach(function(element) {
   if(!in_array(element, unique_array)){
  unique_array.push(element);
   }
 });
    return unique_array
}

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Map, which is type proof and prevents iterating again and again with Array#indexOf.

```
function removeDuplicateUsingFilter(list) {
   filtered = list.filter(function (a) {
     if (!this.has(a.toLowerCase())) {
        this.set(a, true);
        return true;
     }
   }, new Map);
  return filtered.sort()
}

a = ["genesis", "genesis", "ruben", "adeline", "ruben", "adeline", 
"fausto", "lauren", "zeke", "samantha", "Samantha", "Genesis"]

console.log(removeDuplicateUsingFilter(a))

//output: ["adeline", "fausto", "genesis", "lauren", "ruben", "samantha", "zeke"]
```

Comment: Thank you!   but  I've tried it doesn't sort in my code

Comment: Can you provide more context about what problems you're seeing?

Comment: I used your function but my programm doesn't sort alphabetic order names without any duplicated names.

Comment: Can you give me a sample input?

Comment: I updated my answer to provide sample input and output. I'm not sure exactly what behavior you're seeing on your end, but the code works as expected for me.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
const words = [
  "genesis", 
  "genesis", 
  "ruben", 
  "adeline", 
  "ruben", 
  "adeline", 
  "fausto", 
  "lauren", 
  "zeke", 
  "samantha", 
  "Samantha", 
  "Genesis"
 ];

const sorted = Object.keys(words.reduce((res, word) => {
  return {...res, [word]:word}
}, {})).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));

console.log(sorted);
```

[`localCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) function has many options to control sorting, and may handle cases like:

```
 const arr = [ "1", "10", "2" , "1A", "10a", "2a", "10A"];
 arr.sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b, 'en', {numeric: true}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list.filter(
    (elem) => {
         return list.find(elem) === -1 ? true : false;
    }
)
.sort(
    (a,b) => {
         return a > b ? 1 : -1;
    }
);
```

This should work

Comment: Your solution increases sorting complexity from `O(n log n)` to `O(n ^ 2)`